# Automation RBAC requirements for Security Center/Sentinel Playbooks

Tags: azure, azure-logic-apps, azure-security, azure-rbac, azure-sentinel

I am currently in the process of setting up Sentinel POC, within Sentinel you have playbooks which is basically Logic Apps, it is same as the playbooks in security center.

I need to know what permissions i need on target subscriptions in order to automate remediation of alerts, for example isolate a VM, Stop a VM, etc.

Our Sentinel will have its own subscription in a tenant where there are 100's of subscriptions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its best to use a [service principal](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/howto-create-service-principal-portal) for having centralized access control.

With this, you can use the service principal to authenticate and authorize actions against resources. It can be configured for the [Azure Resource Manager](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/connectors/arm/) connector in Logic Apps as well.

[image: logic apps arm connector with service principal]

Another option would be to use [Managed Identity](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/logic-apps/create-managed-service-identity), but that is supported only for the HTTP Action.

As for the exact permissions for this service principal / managed identity, you can [use this reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/role-based-access-control/built-in-roles) of built-in roles for providing granular control. For example, to just stop/start VMs, your service principal would need [Virtual Machine Contributor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/role-based-access-control/built-in-roles#virtual-machine-contributor).

You could also provision finer access to resources by [creating custom roles](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/role-based-access-control/custom-roles).